# Lagrange multipliers problem

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have a two variables function: $f(x,y)=3x+y$ and I wish to find its minimum and maximum values with the constraint $\sqrt{x} +\sqrt{y} =4$. According to the answer, there is a minimum and a maximum. However, I found only 1 point, the minimum, and couldn't find another. MAPLE also found only the minimum. The answer in the answers sheet say that 16 is between the min and max, I can't see why if there is only 1 point. Or maybe there are more ?

Comment: think of both ends.. i.e either $(16,0)$, or $(0,16)$. remember you find *local* maximum/minimum in Lagrange. but if you want absolute, you have to check the edges as well.

Comment: where the 16 comes from ?

Comment: when you put $y=0$ you end with $x=16$ in that case $(16,0)$ is absolute  maximum. and when you put $x=0$ and get $y=16$ - but , given the minimum you found with lagrange , you can check and see $(0,16)$ is neither absolute minimum, neither maximum

Comment: This Mathematica plot should give you an idea of what’s going on: http://i.imgur.com/mslZUzQ.png. The curved blue line is the complete set of points $(x,y)$ where the constraint holds, and the straight lines are, from left to right, the solutions to $f(x,y)=6, f(x,y)=12,\dots, f(x,y)=48$, and $f(x,y)=56$

Comment: x=0 and y=0 are the edges because of the square root, because it's the domain of constraint ?

Comment: yup... always consider your domain of constraint!

Answer (score 0):

As has been remarked in the comments, the Lagrange-multiplier method only looks for level lines, planes, surfaces etc. which are *tangent* to the "constraint" curve, surface, etc.  The constraint $ \ \sqrt{x} \ + \ \sqrt{y} \ = \ 4 \ $ is the portion of the astroid curve (marked in blue) in the first quadrant; "Lagrange" gives you the level curve $ \ f(x) \ = \ 3x \ + \ y \ = \ c \ $ which is tangent to the constraint curve.  Since the level curve is a straight line and the "quarter-astroid" is concave upward, it can only intersect the constraint curve at one point (on the red line).  So the minimum value for  $ \ f ( x ) \ $ is thereby located.

[image]

The maximum must be found (if it exists) in the same way that we look for extrema, for instance, for a function of one variable in a closed interval: after locating any local extrema in the "interior" of the interval, we must also check the endpoints of the interval.  The quarter-astroid has an $ \ x-$ and a $ \ y-$ intercept, so the values of $ \ f(x) \ $ must also be checked at each of those points.  (The green line is the "level curve" for $ \ 3x \ + \ y \ = \ c' \ $ .)  [I won't spoil things by giving the extremal values themselves.]

Comment: thank you for this answer, very helpful